# Usage of Promise in webpack / react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, promise, babeljs, survivejs

I am trying to use Promise in an react app using webpack but I have this error :

`'Promise' is not defined  no-undef`

So far, everything was working well (used babel to translate js and jsx) but unfortunately Promise does not work.

Furthermore, I have this error in Chrome (latest) and I though Promise was buildin feature.... Am I right ?

Here is a piece of config that I use (I used survivejs kanban app as a starter, I am trying to add some functionalities). I did not change much the initial config :

From web pack.config.js

```
module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          // Enable caching for extra performance
          loaders: ['babel?cacheDirectory'],
          include: include
        }
      ]
}
```

From .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Failing code :

```
const locales = {
    en: () => require('react-intl?locale=en!./en.json'),
    fr: () => require('react-intl?locale=fr!./fr.json')
}

function loadLocaleData (locale) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        locales[locale]()(resolve)
    })
}
```

**THE VALID ANSWER IS IN COMMENTS**

Comment: Can we see the code where you call the Promise ?

Comment: for get promise you are suppose to do example `const promise = new Promise((resolve reject) => { your stuff here})`

Comment: Failing code added. Seems pretty close to what you suggest. I also tried with a function, did not work either.

Comment: Seems like `eslint` is giving you this error

Comment: Yeah, seems like `eslint` error to me too. Related: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1921 .

Comment: So either set `/*globals Promise:true*/` locally or do the same at global eslint config to resolve.

Comment: Yes, you were right it was a eslint issue. Fixed locally with /*globals Promise:true*/.

Comment: But I didn't get where I should put the global config, in the .eslintrc file ?

Comment: .eslintrc, yup. The answers show what extra to do.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know you need te include a Promise polyfill in your webpack config. I use:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'Promise': 'exports?global.Promise!es6-promise'
    })
],
```

Where es6-promise is a npm package which will be include when no promise is available or added by any other npm package